# Непонятный феномен java generic

Tags: java

Дан код java

```
public class C {

    interface BT<T> {
        List<String> getList();
    }
    
    public static void method1(BT b) {
        for (String item : b.getList()) {}  // incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
    }

    public static void method2(BT b) {
        for (Object item : b.getList()) {}
    }
    
    public static void method3(BT<Integer> b) {
        for (String item : b.getList()) {}
    }
    
}
```

Почему в методе `method1` возникает ошибка `incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String`?
Ладно бы был `BT<T> { List<T> getList() }`. Но почему параметр `T` имеет такое влияние на метод, который с ним связан лишь тем, что просто оба прописаны в одном интерфейсе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это следствие использования сырого (raw) типа.

При использовании raw типов, как у вас `BT` в методе `method1`, все типы его методов и полей тоже становятся сырыми согласно [спецификации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

Comment: Любопытно было бы узнать, почему принята такая спецификация?